# Typescript code issue when trying to find an item in a Realtime database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am having some problems with Typescript code in a Firebase cloud function.
The function is just meant to search for a record in a database. The item to search for is provided though a value given as argument in *req.query.val*.

I have confirmed that this line is returning what is expected:

```
const snpsv = snapshot.val();
```

The problem comes after.

The complete code is below.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as cors from "cors";

const corsHandler = cors();
admin.initializeApp();

exports.findVALUE = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  let jsonResult;

  corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
    if (req.query.val === undefined) {
      jsonResult = {"Error": "A VALUE to search for must be provided to use this function."};
      resp.send(jsonResult);
    }

    const refStr = "TopCollection/ContentCollection";
    const dbRef = admin.database().ref(refStr);

    dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      const snpsv = snapshot.val(); // Getting a list of items.

      // The forEach loop hereafter is not working !
      // Wrong syntax or some other issue ?
      snpsv.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.get("val") == req.query.val) {
          jsonResult = {"item": item.get("val2")};
          resp.send(jsonResult);
        }
      });
    });
  }); // End corsHandler.
}); /* End of findVALUE */
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
src/index.ts:43:22 - error TS7006: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

43       snpsv.forEach((item) => {
                        ~~~~
```

Finally here is the general structure of the database:

```
TopCollection/ContentCollection
    0  
        fieldOne: ...
        fieldTwo: ...
        url: ...
        otherField: ...
    1  
        fieldOne: ...
        fieldTwo: ...
        url: ...
        otherField: ...
    2  
        fieldOne: ...
        fieldTwo: ...
        url: ...
        otherField: ...
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

this happens when Typescript doesn't know about the type of the `item`.
you can check whether you are using `--noImplicitAny` compiler option. if you are using it, it prevents TypeScript from implicitly assuming the type as any when the type is not specified or the type cannot be inferred from its usage.

to fix this you can do the following,

1. you can mark the type of `item` as any like this. `snpsv.forEach((item: any) => {`
2. you can define the type of the `item` object as an interface

Comment: I have unsuccessfully tried the first solution. I am not sure how to try the second.

Comment: I have edited the post to give the layout of the data in the DB. I need to know the way to find the record matching a value given as argument. And what I am doing is not working.

Comment: try making a class based on the structure of docs in the DB